# Trying to run python script from a Django form

Tags: python, django

I am creating a simple ui which takes 2 files as input and if we press submit button then trying to run script.py (which is Python script) and render output on screen or some output folder

#forms.py

```
from django import forms
class AwsForm ( forms.Form ):
    Aws_SourceFile = forms.FileField ()
    Aws_RefernceFile = forms.FileField ()
```

#views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import AwsForm
import subprocess

def home_view(request):
    context = {}
    context [ 'form' ] = AwsForm ()
    return render ( request , "home.html" , context )

def submit_view(request):
    info = request.POST [ 'info' ]


def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = AwsForm ()
    else:
        if form.is_valid ():
            info = request.POST [ 'info_name' ]
            output = script_function ( info )
            return render ( request , 'myapp/home.html' , {
                'info': info ,
                'output': output ,
            } )
    return render ( request , 'myapp/home.html' , {
        'form': form ,
    } )


def script_function(post_from_form):
    print ( post_from_form )
    return subprocess.check_call ( [ '\script_18122020.py' , post_from_form ] )
```

#urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from myapp.views import home_view, submit_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view ),
    path('submit', submit_view),

]
```

#home.html

```
{% block main_content %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to Adwait Algorithm and Aws.</h1>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <form action="your_view_url" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

<p> Post Data: {{ info }} </p>
<p> Result: {{ output }} </p>
{% endblock main_content %}

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to pickup a script and I want to display the output to a folder or on html file or on screen.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to alter your script function to accept 2 files.
Also change in your template...

```
<form action="your_view_url" method="post">
```

to

```
 <form action="my_view" method="post">
```

Add my_view to your urls.py

forms.py edit these 2 lines

```
Aws_SourceFile = forms.FileField(upload_to='your_directory_name/')
Aws_RefernceFile = forms.FileField(upload_to='your_directory_name/')
```

Views.py .. (my_view) # You need to pass the exact location of your files to the script

```
Aws_SourceFile = request.FILES.get('Aws_SourceFile')
Aws_RefernceFile =request.FILES.get('Aws_RefernceFile')

ASF_dir_file = os.path.join('your_directory_name', Aws_SourceFile.uploadfile.name)

ARF_dir_file = os.path.join('your_directory_name', Aws_RefernceFile.uploadfile.name)


output = script_function ( ASF_dir_file, ARF_dir_file )

def script_function(ASF_dir_file, ARF_dir_file):
    
    output_asf = subprocess.check_call ( [ '\script_18122020.py' , ASF_dir_file] )
    output_asr = subprocess.check_call ( [ '\script_18122020.py' , ARF_dir_file] )
     
    return output_asf, output_asf
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but iam getting error  File "D:\Adwait_gui\trimax\trimaxapp\views.py", line 34
    ASF_dir_file = os.path.join ( "C:\Users\India\Desktop\asf ",Aws_SourceFile.uploadfile.name)
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: from where? can you post a stack trace screenshot?

Comment: Is there a space in the file names you are uploading?

Comment: File "D:\Adwait_gui\trimax\trimaxapp\views.py", line 34
    ASF_dir_file = os.path.join ( "C:\Users\India\Desktop\asf ",Aws_SourceFile.uploadfile.name)
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: what do you get of you print(Aws_SourceFile.uploadfile.name)

Comment: actually my scenario is creating ui in that  user going to seclect 2 files from their desktop and those 2 files will be input to my script and i want to run script  in backend and display output